# Is it possible to select more rows than a table contains?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table than contains 100 rows. I want to select 200 items from it, using random rows to generate more results than the table has rows for:

```
SELECT * FROM `rows` ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 200;
```

This query predictably returns 100 results. Is there a way to randomly select more than is actually contained in the table?

**EDIT**

Is there a way to select an arbitrary number of records without adding compounding `join` statements? For example, what if the requested count (`LIMIT`) of items is unknown in advance or is arbitrarily large?

Comment: It might be helpful to know how you want your random process to work. If you want more results than are available in the table, it seems likely that you want a random table row for each result row, not a random permutation.

Comment: @Medo42, that is correct, I want a random table row for each resulting row, if possible.

Comment: Then the *current* answers below are probably not what you are looking for. I don't have a better idea either though :)

Comment: Not an answer, but if it's possible in your case, maybe consider just loading the table contents into your application and generating your random list from that.

Answer (score 5):

try something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM `rows`
    cross join `rows`
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 200;
```

Comment: Thjat's not going to give you two copies of each column, is it? I thought a cross join would give you the cartesian product (I may be wrong, I haven't checked).

Comment: if you just select rows from first table, you have N first rows, N second rows and so on

Comment: Yes, it will. To prevent this you could use `SELECT r1.* FROM rows AS r1 CROSS JOIN rows AS r2 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 200`. It might even approach the desired probability distribution if the number of rows is large (since the result number will be squared), but I think this query could have problematic performance if the number of rows is large.

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
Select * From (
SELECT * FROM `rows`
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `rows`
) as alotofrows
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 200;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like:

```
select * from rows
union all
select * from rows
order by random()
limit 200
```

Note that the 200 limit isn't actually needed if you can guarantee the table contains 100 rows.

The `union all` gives you two copies (without duplicate removal) and the `order by` then randomises that full data set for you.

Of course, if your table contains 100 and you want *more* than 200, you'll need to tack on a few more unioning clauses.

However, you may find it easier (and more flexible) to simply select the 100 rows, bring them all into an in-memory structure, and then choose which rows you want with *code* rather than SQL.

This will allow you fine control over the selection process, certainly more so than any "SQL gymnastics" we try to write for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

My approach doesn't met "arbitrarily large" requirement but is easily scalable.

First problem is generate N rows. In SQLite I have used views. You may consider also using virtual tables.

```
CREATE VIEW V10 AS SELECT 0 AS Number UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9;
CREATE VIEW V100 AS SELECT V10.Number*10+low.Number AS Number FROM V10 JOIN V10 AS low;
CREATE VIEW V10000 AS SELECT V100.Number*100+low.Number AS Number FROM V100 JOIN V100 AS low;
```

Querying `V10000` will return `Number` from 0 to 9999.

Now you can:

```
SELECT table.* FROM table JOIN (
    SELECT (
        SELECT ROWID+Number*0 AS rndid FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM()
    ) FROM V10000 WHERE Number<200
) ON table.ROWID=rndid;
```

How does it works?

1. Most inner `SELECT` select one random row from `table` and return its `ROWID`, named `rndid`;
2. Intermediate `SELECT` multiplies random rows;
3. Outer `SELECT` match entire `table` rows with `rndid`s returned.

If more then 10000 results are needed, another wider `VIEW` may be created as previous ones.

Footnote: This is a pure SQL(ite) algorithm. Using some kind of programming language, it will probably be most efficient to create a `TEMP TABLE` using repeated `SELECT * FROM`rows`ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;`